# Read/Write binary file using struct in struct

Tags: file, c++11, struct, binary, binaryfiles

I need to create a binary file and write the current state of the struct created.

This struct have a other struct.
Something like this :

```
struct A {
    bool flag=true;
    int n;
};

struct B
{
    int n1;
    A *array;
};
```

How write all in the binary file?

But specially how read from the binary file and load all in the `struct B` again, and then load all in `A *array`.

Thanks a lot.

I tried this way, but sometime give me a exception and block all 
(violation of read access).

HOW WRITE :

```
ofstream save("binary.bin", ios::binary);
    if (!save) {
        cerr << "Error creation file ";
    }
    else {
        save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prova), sizeof(prova));
    }

    binary.close();
```

HOW READ and PRINT:

```
save.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prova), sizeof(prova));
for (size_t i = 0; i != try.n1; ++i)
   {
   cout << "....." << try.n1 <<endl;
   cout << "..... "<< try.array[i].n <<" ";
   cout << ".....: "<<try.array[i].flag<< endl;
  }
```

Comment: Try to override operators >> and << on basic_istream and basic_ostream respectively. Read from Page 98 in https://isocpp.org/files/papers/4-Tour-Algo-draft.pdf

Comment: Is there any relationship between `n1` and the number of elements in `array`?

Comment: Maybe i wrote a solution, but generate a exception. I post under. Thanks to all.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, n1 is the size of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writting a single instance of `A` in binary is simple since its a POD type:

```
std::ofstream outfile = {...};
A a = { ... };
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

Writing a single instance of `B`, OTOH, is not as simple. You'll have to write `n1` first and then the elements from the array.

```
B b = { ... };

// Write the number of elements first.
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&b.n1), sizeof(b.n1));

// Now write the elements.
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(b.array), sizeof(A)*b.n1);
```

Reading from a binary file is, obviously, the inverse of that. Reading to an instance of `A` is simple.

```
std:ifstream infile = { ... };

A a;
infile.read(retinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

Reading to an instance of `B` is a little bit more involved. You'll have to read the size first, then allocate memory for the elements of the array, and then read the elements of the array.

```
B b;

// Read the number of elements
infile.read(retinterpret_cast<char*>(&b.n1), sizeof(b.n1));

// Allocate memory for the elements of the array.
b.array = new A[b.n1];

// Now read the elements of the array.
infile.read(retinterpret_cast<char*>(b.array), sizeof(A)*b.n1);
```

---

You can simplify some of that code by using helper functions that reduce the use of `retinterpret_cast` all over your code.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   template <typename T>
   std::ostream& write(std::ostream& out, T const& pod)
   {
      out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&pod), sizeof(T));
      return out;
   }

   template <typename T>
   std::ostream& write(std::ostream& out, T* array, int numElements)
   {
      out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(array), sizeof(T)*numElements);
      return out;
   }

   template <typename T>
   std:istream read(std::istream& in, T& pod)
   {
      in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pod), sizeof(T));
      return in;
   }

   template <typename T>
   std:istream& read(std:istream& in, T* array, int numElements)
   {
      in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(array), sizeof(T)*numElements);
      return in;
   }
}
```

Now, you can use:

```
// Write a
MyApp::write(outfile, a);

// Read a
MyApp::read(infile, a);

// Write b
MyApp::write(outfile, b.n1);
MyApp::write(outfile, b.array, b.n1);

// Read b
MyApp::write(infile, b.n1);
b.array = new A[b.n1];
MyApp::write(infile, b.array, b.n1);
```

Comment: I used this solution before if you see my update. But generate exception and close the process.

Comment: Return me Exception "Violation in read" in Runtime many times.

Comment: @Master-Antonio, can't tell what could be causing it without looking at actual code. If possible, please create a [mcve] and create another post.

Comment: @Master-Antonio,  use of `salva.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prova), sizeof(prova));
        salva.close();` is a problem. Please read my answer a bit more carefully.

Comment: My english is very bad, sorry so much, can you modify my code, i think is the only way to understand.

Comment: @Master-Antonio, sorry. I won't do that.

Comment: Ok i modified the code in this way. But the size of the array is "infinite", copy the right value but after continue to copy null ... https://pastebin.com/8A8n26yB Something wrong in MyApp::read(infile, b.array, b.n1);

Comment: The line `MyApp::write(salva, prova.macchine);` needs to be `MyApp::write(salva, prova.numero_automobili);`

Comment: @Master-Antonio, You owe be a good beer for the additional consulting work.

Comment: Sure, where are you from, we drink until late morning. XD XD.